# How to throw an std::iostream failure in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, cin

How do I manually throw an std::iostream::failure?
I have a try-catch loop that catches an exception when the user tries to input a non-integer string, however it does not throw an exception if the user tries to input a float since it will try to read everything before the decimal point in a float value. My solution is to manually throw the exception if there is still data remaining in the stream, how do I do that?

```
/*
Sample Implementation Code in C++
Handling Inputs from User in C++
This code only stops running when the user
inputs the appropriate values. Otherwise, the program
will continue asking the user for input.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <limits> //numeric_limits
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {
    std::cin.exceptions(std::ios::failbit); // set exceptions to be thrown when a failbit is set
    int num = 0;
    int den = 0;

    while (true) {
        try {
            std::cout << "Enter numerator: ";
            std::cin >> num;
            if(std::cin.peek() != '\n') {
                //HOW TO DO THIS PART?
                std::iostream::failure e;
                throw e;
            }
            std::cout << "Enter denominator: ";
            std::cin >> den;
            std::cout << "The quotient is " << num/den << std::endl;
        } catch (std::iostream::failure& e){
            std::cout << "Input should be an integer." << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: by `throw std::iostream::failure()` ?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'std::ios_base::failure::failure()'

Comment: `std::ios_base::failure` has a constructor that takes the message string. As for whether throwing an exception here is the right thing is questionable however.

Comment: IMHO the exception system is usually overkill for parsing input like this. I would only consider using exceptions if the parser has encountered something it can not (trivially) recover from.

Comment: yeah, I also don't like using exceptions in C++, it's just that I'm forced to use try catch here

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's as simple as:

```
throw std::iostream::failure("");
```

the important thing I forgot is the empty string ("") since it has a constructor that takes a string argument but not a void argument.

Comment: Doing `std::cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit)` would probably be a lot simpler though.

Comment: oh didn't know that, thanks. would you like to write that as an answer so I can accept it?